# Encountering an error during Next.js Build

Tags: reactjs, npm, next.js, build

⚠ Entire page /reservation deopted into client-side rendering. https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/deopted-into-client-rendering /reservation
⚠ Entire page /properties deopted into client-side rendering. https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/deopted-into-client-rendering /properties
⚠ Entire page / deopted into client-side rendering. https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/deopted-into-client-rendering /
TypeError: fetch failed
at Object.fetch (node:internal/deps/undici/undici:11730:11)
at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5) {
cause: AggregateError
at internalConnectMultiple (node:net:1114:18)
at afterConnectMultiple (node:net:1667:5)
at TCPConnectWrap.callbackTrampoline (node:internal/async_hooks:130:17) {
code: 'ECONNREFUSED',
[errors]: [ [Error], [Error] ]
}
}
TypeError: fetch failed
at Object.fetch (node:internal/deps/undici/undici:11730:11)
at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5) {
cause: AggregateError
at internalConnectMultiple (node:net:1114:18)
at afterConnectMultiple (node:net:1667:5)
at TCPConnectWrap.callbackTrampoline (node:internal/async_hooks:130:17) {
code: 'ECONNREFUSED',
[errors]: [ [Error], [Error] ]
}
}

Error occurred prerendering page "/". Read more: https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/prerender-error
TypeError: fetch failed
at Object.fetch (node:internal/deps/undici/undici:11730:11)
at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)
⚠ Entire page /favorite deopted into client-side rendering. https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/deopted-into-client-rendering /favorite
⚠ Entire page /404 deopted into client-side rendering. https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/deopted-int ✓ Generating static pages (18/18)

> Export encountered errors on following paths:
> /page: /

I don't understand the error. Could you provide a brief explanation, as well as a possible solution to resolve it?

Answer (score 0):

Here's the page for static rendering: https://nextjs.org/docs/app/api-reference/functions/use-search-params#static-rendering

Quote:

> If a route is statically rendered, calling useSearchParams will cause the Client Component tree up to the closest Suspense boundary to be client-side rendered.

> This allows a part of the route to be statically rendered while the dynamic part that uses useSearchParams is client-side rendered.

> We recommend wrapping the Client Component that uses useSearchParams in a  boundary. This will allow any Client Components above it to be statically rendered and sent as part of initial HTML. Example.

You use `useSearchParams` but have no Suspense boundary. They give this example:

```
'use client'
 
import { useSearchParams } from 'next/navigation'
 
export default function SearchBar() {
  const searchParams = useSearchParams()
 
  const search = searchParams.get('search')
 
  // This will not be logged on the server when using static rendering
  console.log(search)
 
  return <>Search: {search}</>
}
```

and:

```
import { Suspense } from 'react'
import SearchBar from './search-bar'
 
// This component passed as a fallback to the Suspense boundary
// will be rendered in place of the search bar in the initial HTML.
// When the value is available during React hydration the fallback
// will be replaced with the `<SearchBar>` component.
function SearchBarFallback() {
  return <>placeholder</>
}
 
export default function Page() {
  return (
    <>
      <nav>
        <Suspense fallback={<SearchBarFallback />}>
          <SearchBar />
        </Suspense>
      </nav>
      <h1>Dashboard</h1>
    </>
  )
}
```

The error message you get is simply stating that your rendering by `useSearchParams` was done entirely by client-side rendering because there was no [Suspense boundary](https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/routing/loading-ui-and-streaming#example) to specify what to render client-side, therefore it was assumed that the entire page is to be rendered client-side. You will simply need to use a Suspense boundary wrapped around your resources that you want to render on client-side, so the other parts that you want to be statically rendered will be complying to your expectations.

The issue happened at `/` and `/404` at your end.